# How to extract all used functions in SAS programs?

Tags: regex, function, sas

I am planning to do analysis on programming habits recently. One of my job is extracting all used functions in SAS programs which is wroten by many of my colleagues.
I have tried Perl regular function but failed, here is what I get so far.

The content of SAS program file: `test.sas`

```
data test;
  set sashelp.class(firstobs=2) end=eof;

  x = rand('uniform',0,1)- 0.5;
  if sign(round(x,.1));
  y = %sysfunc(date());
  if eof then call execute('dm "postmessage ''42''" continue;');
run;
```

My trial of extracting:

```
data _null_;
  infile 'test.sas' truncover;
  input prog $1024.;

  start = 1;
  stop = length(prog);
  FuncPat = prxparse('/\b[a-zA-Z_]\w*\(/');
  call prxnext(FuncPat, start, stop, prog, position, length);
  do while (position > 0);
    found = substr(prog, position, length-1);
    put found=;
    call prxnext(FuncPat, start, stop, prog, position, length);
  end;
run;
```

So I have:

```
found=class
found=rand
found=sign
found=round
found=sysfunc
found=date
found=execute
```

What I want is:

```
found=rand
found=sign
found=round
found=date
```

**Note:**

1. macro function and subroutine is not included;
2. user-defined function should not be ignored;
3. if the function name is a macro variable, like `&function()`, drop it;

Thanks for any hints.
Remind by @Basile Starynkevitch, here is defintion of [function](https://documentation.sas.com/?cdcId=pgmsascdc&cdcVersion=9.4_3.5&docsetId=lefunctionsref&docsetTarget=p0cbdzgrjala4sn1vamojmh5gmhl.htm&locale=en).
PS: If function `substr(left of =)` is solved, I would double my thanks.
PS2: I am not going to do any parsing work about SAS, just extracting all the text pattern of `function()`, by perl regular expression. It is a very good anwser from @Dirk Horsten.

Comment: @Basile Starynkevitch SAS is not an open source language, but the idea of abstract syntax tree sounds nice, I will try.

Comment: Or write your own SAS parser in [Ocaml](https://ocaml.org/) using [Menhir](http://cambium.inria.fr/~fpottier/menhir/). BTW, I am interested in understanding *why do you ask*? What you need at first is a specification (probably in [EBNF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Backus%E2%80%93Naur_form) notation) of the syntax of the SAS language. Everything else is a classic exercise in [parsing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsing) so you could take inspiration from open source implementations

Comment: ... Implementations like like [GNU guile](https://www.gnu.org/software/guile/) or [Pÿthon](https://python.org/)

Comment: @Basile Starynkevitch OK,  Abstract syntax tree is a nice choice but I think we have a little off topic. My task is extracting all functions, isn't it?

Comment: Yes, but you first need to define (on paper) what is a function, using EBNF notation. Then you need to code a parser. Budget several weeks of full-time work. I don't know SAS, but it could have [anonymous functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anonymous_function).... or classes with methods, etc...

Comment: Another source of inspiration could be [GNU octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/) or [Scilab](https://www.scilab.org/). Both are open source, you are allowed to study their source code and take inspiration from it

Comment: @Basile Starynkevitch you're right, I'll add the definition of function, but I am not going to write a parser. I only count frequncy for different functions, not do the parsing works, so parser is not needed. On the other hand, Writing a parser is too hard for me.

Comment: So according to your definition, `data` is a function

Comment: @Basile Starynkevitch Sorry, I give you the offcial defintion this time.

Comment: This is not a definition, but a semantics. You need the *syntax* of functions (preferably using EBNF notation). In many software teams, you also have some *coding conventions*. A good example is [GNU coding standards](https://www.gnu.org/prep/standards/), but your organization/team has probably its own ones. For example, the source code of [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) has many of them. And your software development process has some [code review](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_review) activity

Comment: Also, edit your question to explain how many functions definitions are in your `test.sas`  example. I see none. But I guess 5 function applications are there.....

Comment: FYI, there are ~600 SAS functions, ~65 data step statements, ~400 procs, ~600 system options, etc. Get the list of functions identified then try and go for them.

Comment: SAS does not have classes, properties, methods, or any other OOP type of construct. It has 2 step boundaries: data and proc. Each proc is its own language structure and is independent of the others. There may be some commonality but it is somewhat superficial. There is some commonality in the meta-languages such as the dataset modifiers. Likewise, the functions operate the same with their own structures. You will also find the functions re-used depending on the left side of the equals vs right.(see SUBSTR).

Comment: Any SAS source file that contains macro code is pretty much immune from full analysis.  Use of macro can break parsers because the actual code is not known until it's being run by SAS processor.  If you have lots of SAS code that is being submitted somewhat regularly, IIRC there are SAS options that can do execution profiling that records time spent in which routines.  Can't recall the exact option or command at this time, but Joe or Tom might.

Comment: @Richard Let's treat macro as macro, not unwrapped code. I' ll do the same analysis on macros using later.

Comment: Look at this work: https://github.com/xueqilsj/sas-grammar using ANTLR

Answer (score 2):

Ok, lots of theory here. I have worked on the SAS language parsing and it is very, very complex. Hopes of cracking that problem in a reasonable timeframe are not practical. Let me start with the lex. SAS has hundreds of functions and they vary a lot in parameters. You have macro functions and regular functions.

There are no lexers/parsers for SAS outside of SAS and WPL. Attempts have been made by a number of people but I am unaware of any successful ones other than WPL. It took them millions of dollars and a large team of people. If you want to only look at functions, start with only focusing on the data step and get the lex first.

BTW, I have tried this with ANTLR but, IMO, it is not necessary. Go simple and break by semi-colon to determine the lines. You have 2 main parts of a SAS program: the DATA step and the PROC. Break there, then by lines, then try and isolate the functions within the line. It will not be 100% but it is an attempt.

IMO, ignore this lexer/parser, this theory, this approach, this sample language, etc. The SAS language is 50+ years old and contains hundreds of sub-languages, hundreds of PROCs, hidden features, and several meta-languages on top (macros, dataset modifiers, ODS, etc.).

Good luck.

Comment: It is a little off my problem, but still let me learn a lot. Thanks, @AlanC.

Answer (score 2):

Just check what is in front what of you found before you use it. (The scan function with a negative position counts from the end of the string instead of the beginning.)

Further: Instead of writing to the log, you better `output` to a dataset, so you can run statistics on the result.

```
data FUNCTION;
  infile 'test.sas' truncover;
  input prog $1024.;

  start = 1;
  stop = length(prog);
  FuncPat = prxparse('/\b[a-zA-Z_]\w*\(/');
  call prxnext(FuncPat, start, stop, prog, position, length);
  do while (position > 0);
    found = substr(prog, position, length-1);
    if not ( substr(prog, position - 1) eq '.'
          or substr(prog, position - 1) eq '%'
          or upcase(scan(substr(prog, 1, position - 1), -1)) eq 'CALL'
          or upcase(scan(substr(prog, 1, position - 1), -1)) eq 'DATA'
    ) then output;
    call prxnext(FuncPat, start, stop, prog, position, length);
  end;
run;
```

You might come up to other constructs that are not really functions which you want to exclude, but thus should be a good start.